# Where is the supervisor keep a process's pidfile?

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

#### Error explain:

I do a django-celery project and use supervisor to keep the celery process.

With a lot of action,it mad out a error that I can't start a work.It says:

> stale pidfile exists.Removing it.

But i did not point the pidfile path when I setting the supervisor.

#### question

- where is the supervisor keep the process's pidfile default?
- Could someone tell me how to right do command that I can see the tasks and workers in django-admin-site? I try like this when I develop the projects:

  - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8090
  - python manage.py celery events --camera=djcelery.snapshot.Camera
  - python manage.py celerybeat -l INFO
  - python manage.py celeryd -n worker_1 -l INFO

  But when I try like this in supervisor,with nginx+uwsgi,I see nothing in django-admin-site

Comment: What's more,  the supervisor keep the process at before but no do tasks

Comment: I change way to run supervisor. I do work throuth process=4 and process_name = xxx_%(process_num)s and celeryd -n work_%(process_num)s.at begin,4 worker would be running by supervisorctl status.But at the moument,4 worker would change status,it seems they are being stop -> begin -> stop -> begin.Why be like this?Could somebody help me?

Comment: The detail is in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005490/why-the-supervisor-make-the-celery-worker-changing-form-running-to-starting-all