# Why the supervisor make the celery worker changing form running to starting all the time?

Tags: python, django, django-celery, supervisord

## backgroud

The system is Centos7, which have a python2.x. 1GB memory and single core.

I install python3.x , I can code python3 into python3.

The django-celery project is based on a virtualenv python3.x,and I had make it well at nginx,uwsgi,mariadb. At least,I think so for no error happend.

I try to use supervisor to control the django-celery's worker,like below:

```
command=env/bin/python project/manage.py celeryd -l INFO -n worker_%(process_num)s
numprocs=4
process_name=projects_worker_%(process_num)s
stdout_logfile=logfile.log
etderr_logfile=logfile_err.log
```

Also had make setting about celery events,celery beat,this part is well ,no error happend. Error comes from the part of worker.

When I keep the proces big than 1,it would run at first,when I do `supervisorctl status`,all are running.

But when I do the same command to see status once more times,some process status change to starting.

So I try more times,I found that:the worker's status would always change from running to starting and then changeing starting to running-- no stop.

When I check the supervisor's logfile at tmp/supervisor.log,it shows like:

```
exit status 1; not expected
entered runnging state,process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds(startsecs)
'project_worker_0' with pid 2284
```

Maybe it shows why the worker change status all the time.

What's more ,when I change the proces to 1,the worker could failed.The worker's log show me:

```
stale pidfile exists.Removing it
```

But,I did not ponit the pidfile path to worker.And,I just found the events's and beat 's pidfie at the `/` path,no worker's pidfile.Also ,I try `find / -name *.pid` to find a pidfile like worker,or celeryd,but here did not exist.

## question

- firstly, I want to deploy the project , so ,did here any other way to deploy the django-celery with virtulanev's  celery part?
- If here anyone can tell me how this phenomenon comes,I would better to choose supervisor to deploy the celery part. Anyone can help me about it ?

## PS

Any of your thoughts may be helpful to me, best wishs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem yesterday night.

### about the reason

- I make the project could success running at a windows 10 system, but did no check when I change the project to centos7.+. The command:`env/bin/python project/manage.py celeryd` could not run success. So the supervisor would start a process which will failed soon.
- Why the command could not success? I had pip installed all the package need. But it show err below:

  > Running a worker with superuser privileges when the worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!
  >
  > If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
  >   environment variable (but please think about this before you do).
  >
  > User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  I try to search some blog about this error, and get the anser:

  > export C_FORCE_ROOT='true' # at the centos enviroument

### action to solve(after meeting error like this)

- add `export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'` to centos's enviroment file and source it.
- check command 'env/bin/python project/manage.py celeryd ',did it run successful.
- restart the supervisord. Attention please! not `supervisorctl reload`,it just reload the .conf file,not the environment file. Try kill the process `supervisord -c xx.conf`(`ps aux | grep supervisord` and `kill -9 process_number`,be careful).

### some url about the blog

- [the error when just run celeryd not sucess](http://xiaorui.cc/2014/04/23/python%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8celery%E5%81%9A%E5%BC%82%E6%AD%A5%E4%BB%BB%E5%8A%A1%E6%97%B6%E7%9A%84%E5%B8%B8%E8%A7%81%E7%9A%84%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/)  in chinese